# Electroserver Db Extension

Tags: database

I use electroserver for my game development and i need to understand how the db login mysql example in the site works.. Because in 2 places they have called the controller.registerNewUser function (in dbloginhandler.java and databaseplugin.java)..im unable to trace the execution so please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you read [this tutorial](http://www.electrotank.com/docs/es5/manual/database_examples.htm) first.

In `DbLoginMySQL`, your `Extension.xml` will have `useTwoStepLogin` set to `false`, so if a user registers it will be done in `DBLoginHandler.java`, which then calls `Controller.registerNewUser`.  In the similar `TwoStepLogin` example, `useTwoStepLogin` is set to `true`, and any registration is done by a plugin request to `DatabasePlugin`.

Originally the two examples were going to be a single example, with explanation of how to switch from one configuration to another by editing `Extension.xml`. In testing we decided to make them two separate examples, and add the example room plugin to the `TwoStepLogin`, to show how a game can check that a user hasn't tried to bypass the second login step.